# BackgroundService не может корректно завершиться

Tags: c#, .net-core

Не могу понять, почему мой `BackgroundService` (.NET Core 3.1) не может корректно завершить свою работу.

Написал сервис, который должен слушать tcp-порт и обрабатывать сообщения определенного формата. Написал следующий `BackgroundService`:

```
internal sealed class TcpListenerBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ITcpPortListener _tcpPortListener;
    private readonly ILogger<TcpListenerBackgroundService> _logger;

    public TcpListenerBackgroundService(ITcpPortListener tcpListener, ILogger<TcpListenerBackgroundService> logger)
    {
        _tcpPortListener = tcpListener;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        try
        {
            await _tcpPortListener.ListenAsync(stoppingToken);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Unexpected error was occured");
        }
    }
}
```

Сюда в качестве `ITcpPortListener` внедряется следующий `TcpPortListener`:

```
public sealed class TcpPortListener : ITcpPortListener
{
    private readonly ILogger<TcpPortListener> _logger;
    private readonly IPacketProcessor _packetProcessor;
    private readonly TcpListener _listener;
    private TaskCompletionSource<object> _appTerminationSource;

    public TcpPortListener(
        ITcpPortListenerConfiguration config,
        IPacketProcessor packetProcessor,
        ILogger<TcpPortListener> logger)
    {
        _listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, config.PortNumber);
        _packetProcessor = packetProcessor;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task ListenAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _appTerminationSource = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        await using (stoppingToken.Register(_appTerminationSource.SetCanceled))
        {
            var taskList = new List<Task>();
            _listener.Start();

            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var acceptClientTask = _listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                await Task.WhenAny(acceptClientTask, _appTerminationSource.Task);

                if (acceptClientTask.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
                {
                    var client = acceptClientTask.Result;
                    var processTask = ProcessClientAsync(client, stoppingToken);

                    taskList.Add(processTask);
                }

                taskList.RemoveAll(p => p.IsCompleted);
            }

            _logger.LogInformation("Waiting for all clients termination...");
            await Task.WhenAll(taskList.ToArray());

            _logger.LogInformation("Terminate listening...");
            _listener.Stop();
            _logger.LogInformation("Listening was terminated successfully!");
        }
    }

    private async Task ProcessClientAsync(TcpClient client, CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        var clientIp = GetClientIp(client);
        _logger.LogInformation($"Client[{clientIp}]. Connected");

        try
        {
            var stream = client.GetStream();
            var socket = client.Client;

            _logger.LogInformation($"Client[{clientIp}]. Start processing");

            var buffer = new byte[1024];
            var packetContainer = new SuntechPacketContainer();
            var isSocketConnected = CheckSocketConnection(socket);

            while (isSocketConnected && !stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var readTask = stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, stoppingToken);
                await Task.WhenAny(readTask, _appTerminationSource.Task);

                if (readTask.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
                {
                    var bytesRead = readTask.Result;
                    if (bytesRead == 0)
                    {
                        isSocketConnected = false;
                        break;
                    }

                    packetContainer.Append(buffer.Take(bytesRead));
                    var packets = packetContainer.FetchFullPackets();
                    await ProcessPacketsAsync(packets);

                    isSocketConnected = CheckSocketConnection(socket);
                }
            }

            if (!isSocketConnected)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"Client[{clientIp}]. Socket disconnected. The message processing for the client has been stopped");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, $"Client[{clientIp}]. Unexpected error was occured during client processing");
        }
        finally
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Client[{clientIp}]. Closing the client connection");
            client.Close();
        }
    }

    private static string GetClientIp(TcpClient client)
    {
        return ((IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString();
    }

    private async Task ProcessPacketsAsync(IEnumerable<byte[]> packets)
    {
        foreach (var packet in packets)
        {
            await _packetProcessor.ProcessPacketAsync(packet);
        }
    }

    private static bool CheckSocketConnection(Socket socket)
    {
        const int connectionTimeoutInMicroseconds = 1_000;

        var poll = socket.Poll(connectionTimeoutInMicroseconds, SelectMode.SelectRead);
        return !((poll && (socket.Available == 0)) || !socket.Connected);
    }
}
```

Развернул этот сервис на CentOS 7 с помощью `systemd`.

Проблема в том, что иногда (не знаю точно, при каких условиях), если к сервису подключен хотя бы один клиент, и в этот момент я захочу остановить сервис (вызвать `service stop`), то сервис будет бесконечно завершаться и `systemd` повиснет, из-за чего придется убивать ее, после чего, узнав статус сервиса, мне будет сказано, что процесс был убит из-за истечения таймаута ожидания. Я совсем не могу понять, почему так происходит, ведь по логам метод `ListenAsync` отработал. Это точно не из-за того, что метод `ListenAsync` долго завершается. Прилагаю пример логов:

```
//...
2020-11-03 04:01:22.299 -05:00 [INF] Application is shutting down...
2020-11-03 04:01:22.333 -05:00 [INF] Client[127.0.0.1]. Closing the client connection
2020-11-03 04:01:22.334 -05:00 [INF] Waiting for all clients termination...
2020-11-03 04:01:22.335 -05:00 [INF] Terminate listening...
2020-11-03 04:01:22.336 -05:00 [INF] Listening was terminated successfully!
```

Есть ощущение, будто в некоторых случаях не освобождаются все ресурсы. Прошу проинспектировать мой код на наличие возможных неточностей с управлением ресурсами. Мой глаз уже намылен, ничего не видит.

Comment: Подсказка: `Task.WhenAll(taskList.ToArray());` - `.ToArray()` можно убрать, он лишний.

Comment: _вызвать `service stop`_ - что этот метод делает? канселлит ли он токен? Отлавливаются ли все места, где может быть выброшена `OperationCancelledException` в резальтате отмены токена? А может такое быть, что система сама перезапускает сервис? Может в процессе завершения вываливается исключение, и процесс завершается с ненулевым exit кодом?

Comment: @aepot а что означает по вашему "рабочий код"? Я, например, не могу найти точного определения для этого словосочетания (мне кажется, это будет хороший вопрос на мете). `Код запускается?` Определенно, да. `Код выполняет свои основные функции?` Определенно, да. Единственное, что код не всегда корректно справляется с задачей завершения работы.

Comment: @aepot по поводу тега `backgroundworker` - я перепутал с понятием (`WorkerService`)(https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#worker-service-template) в dotnet core. Спасибо, поправил.

Comment: @aepot все же я соглашусь. Цель инспекции кода - найти недостатки кода, а не устранять баги

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if (readTask.IsCompletedSuccessfully)` вот здесь ошибка. Если будет `false`, оно просто пропустит обработку и пойдет читать дальше по циклу, и так оно может запустить миллион тасков, которые будут ждать что-то там из сокета. Мне кажется, надо сделать `break` цикла.

Eсли `WhenAny` отработал через `_appTerminationSource.Task`, вам обязательно надо где-то вызвать `await readTask`, чтобы убедиться что операция чтения завершена прежде чем гасить клиент. Возможно оттуда даже исключение выбросится при `await`.

Попробуйте такой паттерн

```cs
while (isSocketConnected && !stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    using CancellationTokenSource localCts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(stoppingToken);

    var readTask = stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, localCts.Token);

    var fastTask = await Task.WhenAny(readTask, _appTerminationSource.Task);
    
    // WhenAny не дождался readTask, надо канселить локальный токен и завершать цикл
    // (или не завершать цикл, это уж вам решать)
    if (fastTask != readTask)
    {
        localCts.Cancel();
        await readTask; // здесь с большой вероятностью вывалится OperationCanceledException
        break;
    }

    if (readTask.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
    {
        var bytesRead = readTask.Result;
        if (bytesRead == 0)
        {
            isSocketConnected = false;
            break;
        }

        packetContainer.Append(buffer.Take(bytesRead));
        var packets = packetContainer.FetchFullPackets();
        await ProcessPacketsAsync(packets);

        isSocketConnected = CheckSocketConnection(socket);
    }
}
```

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, объяснить, почему вы в этом месте `var readTask = stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, localCts.Token);` передаете ликованный токен, если можно передать `stoppingToken`?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko потому что я его локально отменяю не отменяя `stoppingToken`, чисто чтобы завершить `readTask` немедленно. При этом цикл может продолжить выполняться, и `stoppingToken` может быть не отменен при этом. Я просто встроил защиту от заброшенного таска. Как вы и просили - правильное управление ресурсами. Можете оптимизировать, я просто как идею это вам даю.

Comment: Тут самая большая проблема в том, что метод `stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, localCts.Token);` бесконечно (или очень-очень долго) будет выполняться, если данные не приходят. И stoppingToken не помогает, к сожалению, завершить эту таску. Об этом написано [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12431633/6468198). Проверено на практике

Comment: Так ведь условие `if (fastTask != readTask)` выполнится только тогда, когда `_appTerminationSource.Task` завершится, т.е. `stoppingToken` станет `Cancelled`. Поэтому все равно не понимаю, зачем вручную завершать токен, если внутри `if` stoppingToken всегда будет `Cancelled`. Может быть, я чего-то не понимаю

Comment: @AndreiKhotko окей, тогда выбросите все лишнее и оставьте только `if (fastTask != readTask) { break; }`. Просто если не дожидаться `readTask`, тогда продолжать чтение из сокета вообще нельзя, путь только на выход. С другой стороны, не дождавшись завершения всех задач (если делать все правильно), не стоит завершать сервис. Именно брошенные (не ожидаемые) таким образом таски и приводят в выше указанным вами проблемам.

Comment: Вот я тоже думаю. Вероятно, нужно как-то оборвать этот ожидающий `task` моментально. Через `await` - не вариант, потому что будет бесконечно. Ставить таймер на эту задачу тоже нельзя, поскольку сообщения идут раз в 2 минуты. Таймаут в 3 минуты - слишком долго для завершения приложения. Видел такое предложение - зарегистрировать на токен `stream.Close`. Тогда метод чтения упадет с ошибкой.

Comment: я не вижу, что такое `_appTerminationSource.Task`, могу только догадываться, а про связь этой таски с `stoppingToken` только вам известно. Следовательно, я не учитываю никакиет такие гарантии, что токен будет отменен.

Comment: Неправда! Взгляните в метод `ListenAsync`, первые две строчки.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko _зарегистрировать на токен `stream.Close`_ - очень хорошая идея. А про токен - проглядел, да. Ок.

Comment: Оказывается, у меня не закрывалось приложение из-за того, что я не реализовал `Dispose` для клиента очереди (EasyNetQ) и не вызывал его...